# How do I disable a UITextView when swiping to delete a cell in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview

I have a UITableView with custom cells. Each cell has an UIImageview and a UITextView. When the UITextView is tapped on the keyboard appears and the textView border is highlighted.

This is fine but only when a user intends to enter something into the UITextview. My issue comes when a user is swiping to delete the cell. Basically as the user swipes, because the textView takes up half of the cell, the cell is tapped at the same time as the swipe.

So the by the time the delete button appears on the cell, the keyboard has appeared and the textView's border is highlighted.

[image]

What I want to do is resignFirstResponder or endEditing as soon as the swipe begins.

I've tried to this in:

canEditRowAtIndexPath and commitEditingStyle

However there is no effect. I've even tried to disable user interaction and this also has zero effect.

How can I disable the uitextview during a swipe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at the editing methods on the cell in your subclass?

Comment: @Wain this was the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try in tableView(_:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:)

> This method is called when the user swipes horizontally across a row;
>   as a consequence, the table view sets its editing property to true
>   (thereby entering editing mode) and displays a Delete button

It is an UITableView Delegate Method.
Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Worked great. I actually had a button covering my textView and should have been disabling user interaction on that. I used the method you suggested along with the didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Yes I should add this method to in the answer.